# Mercurial internal Setup on Windows 7 - Exception happened during processing of request from 

Tags: mercurial

Hy,

i have 1 central repository and many locals.
On my machine i have local and a central repository too.
I can make clone/commit/update/push/pull very easy between the local and central repository on my local machine.
but when i want to make a clone from another machine it gets an error.

```
listening at http://MyLocalMachine:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.194', 49319)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 558, in process_request_thread
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 320, in finish_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 47, in __init__
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 615, in __init__
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 329, in handle
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 323, in handle_one_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 79, in do_GET
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 70, in do_POST
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 63, in do_write
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 127, in do_hgweb
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 86, in __call__
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 118, in run_wsgi
ErrorResponse
----------------------------------------
```

The command line wich started the central repo:

```
hg serve -R TT -n TTZoli
```

The command from remote machine for cloning:

```
hg clone --pull http://MyLocalMachine:8000/TT
```

Config for the central repo:

```
[ui]
username = MyLocalUserName
username = test <localemail@mail.com> 
with this user i'm trying to acces the central repo

[web]
push_ssl = false
```

Config for the remote repo:

```
[ui]
username = test <localemail@mail.com>     

[web]
push_ssl = false
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant,my firewall is turned off on both machines, and the files in /hg folder are not versioned on the server, except hgignore.

Could you please suggest some ideas? 
What could be the problem? 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
hg clone --pull http://MyLocalMachine:8000
```

I haven't seen the `-R` option before. Is that from a plugin?

Comment: The `-R` is short for `--repository`. It is a global option which is why it isn's shown in `hg help serve` — use `hg help serve -v` to see it.

Answer (score 1):

What directory do you have the local repos serving from?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468805/problem-with-mercurial-hg-serve-command), where that was the source of the problem..